# Datatables - Nested SELECT's & Joins

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I'm using datatables.net but I'm struggling to work out how I can get nested queries and joins to work. I just cant seem to find any examples. I can get it to show simple queries using something like this (For a different table):

```
// DB table to use
$table = 'support_msgs';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'user_id',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'title',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'msg',   'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'date',   'dt' => 4 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'user',
    'pass' => 'pass',
    'db'   => 'db',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);


require( 'ssp.class.php' );

// echo json_encode(
//     SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
// );
echo json_encode(
    SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

But now, I have this query and I can't see anything that would point me in the right direction for this:

```
    SELECT
        vp.id, 
        vp.post_title,
        (
            SELECT 
                    vpm.meta_value 
            FROM 
                    vhyky_postmeta vpm 
            WHERE   vp.id = vpm.post_id
            AND     vpm.meta_key = 'cs_cause_goal_amount'
        ) AS Bonus,
        (
            SELECT 
                    vpm.meta_value
            FROM 
                    vhyky_postmeta vpm 
            WHERE   vp.id = vpm.post_id
            AND     vpm.meta_key = 'cs_cause_raised_amount'
        ) AS Deposit,
        wt.name,
        vp.post_content
FROM 
        vhyky_posts vp,
        vhyky_postmeta vpm,
        vhyky_term_relationships wtr,
        vhyky_term_taxonomy wtt,
        vhyky_terms wt
WHERE   vp.post_type = 'cs_cause'
AND     vp.post_status = 'publish'
AND     vp.id = vpm.post_id
AND     vp.id = wtr.object_id
AND     wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
AND     wt.term_id = wtt.term_id
AND     wtt.term_id = '114'
group by vp.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a view-like table (like a SQL view, not an MVC view) : assembling all needed colums in a new table. You could have a PHP script emptying and filling the table everytime a user asks for data to be displayed. Then, querying with DataTables would be easier (especially if filters are necessary).

Answer (score 1):

I would try to create your query in this manner.  Since I do not know how your Database tables are setup I would not be able to help you more than just editing some syntax.

```
SELECT 
    vp.id,
    vp.post_title,
    bonus.meta_value,
    deposit.meta_value,
    wt.name,
    vp.post_content
FROM
    vhyky_posts vp,
    vhyky_term_relationships wtr,
    vhyky_term_taxonomy wtt,
    vhyky_terms wt
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        vpm.post_id, vpm.meta_value
    FROM
        vhyky_postmeta vpm
    WHERE
        vpm.meta_key = 'cs_cause_goal_amount'
) AS bonus ON bonus.post_id = vp.id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        vpm.post_id, vpm.meta_value
    FROM
        vhyky_postmeta vpm
    WHERE
        vpm.meta_key = 'cs_cause_raised_amount'
) AS deposit ON deposit.post_id = vp.id
WHERE
    vp.post_type = 'cs_cause'
        AND vp.post_status = 'publish'
        AND vp.id = wtr.object_id
        AND wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wt.term_id = wtt.term_id
        AND wtt.term_id = '114'
GROUP BY vp.id
```